# Specify size for each subquery in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have query that is similar to union operation in SQL. What i need is to specify the size of result set for each index. For example i want to get 10 records from first index and 15 records from second index.

My query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "match_phrase_prefix": {"userName": "ar" }
                        }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "match_phrase_prefix": { "groupName": "ar" }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Url to send query:
`http://website.com:9200/user_data,group_data/_search`

If you have any thoughts i'd be very grateful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for help

Eventually i've chosen another approach. I use [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html), which allows you executing several requests at once. My query is:

```
POST http://website.com:9200/_msearch

{"index": "user_data"}
{"size":10,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase_prefix":{"userName":"##USER_TEXT##"}}]}}}
{"index": "group_data"}
{"size":15,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase_prefix":{"groupName":"##USER_TEXT##"}}]}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do that with a simple query.

But can do that with the [Top Hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), which lets you group result sets by certain fields via a bucket aggregator. Your case should look like:

```
{
     "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "match_phrase_prefix": {"userName": "ar" }
                        }]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "match_phrase_prefix": { "groupName": "ar" }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
     }, #Your query stills the same
     "size": 0, #This will bring back nothing within the field "hits", so you can focus in the "aggregations" field.
     "aggs": {
         "10_usernames": {
             "top_hits": {
                 "_source": {
                     "includes": [ "userName" ]
                 },
                 "size" : 10
             }
         },
         "15_groupames": {
             "top_hits": {
                 "_source": {
                     "includes": [ "groupName" ]
                 },
                 "size" : 15
             }
         }

     }
}
```

You'll see your results within the "aggregations" field.

Hope this is helpful! :D